# SlickGrid - frozen columns hover function

Tags: jquery, slickgrid

I am using jlynch's implementation (http://jlynch7.github.io/SlickGrid/examples/example-frozen-columns.html) to get my grid columns frozen. But if the columns are frozen, the hover functionality is not working. The frozen column alone has an independent hover and the rest of the columns have an independent hover. I need to get the same hover for both the frozen column and the rest of the grid.

However, Row selection selects the entire row in the grid. Because i have passed the option - selectActiveRow: true option in RowSelectionModel.

pls help me out here.

Comment: please update some code

Comment: I had to add grid.onMouseEnter and grid.onMouseLeave events to style the frozen column.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by using [slickgrid version](http://jlynch7.github.io/SlickGrid/slick.grid.js).
In this, the file you may get an error like '***can't access property length of undefined, data is undefined.***'

To solve this error add if condition in `setFrozenOptions()` as below.

```
function setFrozenOptions() {
        debugger;
        options.frozenColumn = (options.frozenColumn >= 0
            && options.frozenColumn < columns.length
            )
            ? parseInt(options.frozenColumn)
            : -1;

        options.frozenRow = (options.frozenRow >= 0
            && options.frozenRow < numVisibleRows
            )
            ? parseInt(options.frozenRow)
            : -1;

        if (options.frozenRow > -1) {
            hasFrozenRows = true;
            frozenRowsHeight = (options.frozenRow) * options.rowHeight;
            //added this if condition to solve the undefined error
            if(this.data!=undefined){
            var dataLength = getDataLength() || this.data.length;
            actualFrozenRow = (options.frozenBottom)
                ? (dataLength - options.frozenRow)
                : options.frozenRow;
                }
        } else {
            hasFrozenRows = false;
        }
    }
```